# javascript refresh page after 5 secs

Tags: javascript, php

```
<a href="newpage.php" target="_blank" onClick="openWindowReload(this)">update</a>
    <script>
        function openWindowReload(link) {
            var href = link.href;
        window.open(href,'_blank');
        document.location.reload(true)
        }
</script>
```

so i have this code that automatically refreshing the current page after clicking the link 'update'

what i want is to refresh the current page after 5 secs....why?

in the newpage.php i am updating a table and if the current page reload very fast it will not get the data that is updated, instead it will get the old data...ps sorry for my bad english. . . .

is there any way that i can pause javascript that will refresh the current page..if there is can u guys tell me how....

thanks in advance....

update:

```
<script>
        setTimeout(function openWindowReload(link) {
        var href = link.href;
        window.open(href,'_blank');
        document.location.reload(true)
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

i tried to use time out but its not working.....

Comment: you can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to delay the function, please note you will probably also need to add `return false` to the end of your function so the default action of the a doesn't fire

Comment: hi, im not sure how to do that but i try to put `return false;` at the end  but still its not working.

Comment: try `onClick="openWindowReload(this); return false;"` using putvande's answer as your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.location.reload(true);
}, 5000);
```

That is a way of 'pausing' JavaScript, or better, waiting to execute a bit of functionality.

So it would be:

```
function openWindowReload(link) {
    var href = link.href;
    window.open(href,'_blank');
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.reload(true);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: You want to click the update button, open a window, wait 5 seconds and reload the page right? That is what this code is doing.

Comment: wow thank you, so i used `setTimeout` in a wrong way...thank u very much

Comment: to have better view I propose the integration of AJAX to update juste a div in the page.

Comment: sorry but im just a newbie in javascript and AJAX...but i want to do that.to refresh a particular div only...

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to open window by `javascript` code, due to security reason, the dynamic popup/window would be block until you are not allowing to open popup.

the code will be work fine if you allow popup on browser

```
<a href="newpage.php" target="_blank" onClick="return openWindowReload(this)">update</a>

<script>
      function openWindowReload(link) {
          setTimeout(function(){  
          var href = link.href;
            window.open(href,'_blank');
            document.location.reload(true)
            }, 5000);
          return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to accomplish, I would use an AJAX call to the server to do the table update, and assuming the update is synchronous (your service waits until update is complete before returning), you then update the client content or refresh the page from the callback event handler. That way you dont have to wait an arbitrary time, plus if you have decided you need 5sec, then there may be times when even 5sec wont be enough.

The root of the problem seems to be a race condition from not simply querying the table from the same connection that did the update. Most updates finish in less than a second, you could just block the initial page while you do both operations in serial fashion, and avoid the race condition.

Comment: That was my idea too, to use AJAX. But not sure if it really answers the question.

Comment: True, though he did include his ultimate goal in the question, and the ajax approach is really about the only elegant way, otherwise you either block the original request, or you poll, do you agree?

Comment: Yes I agree, AJAX makes more sense.

Comment: im still in the learning stage in using AJAX but can u pls tell me how to solve my problem using ajax.....if ur not too busy doing something...

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" name="update" class="update">Update</button> 


$(".update").on('click', function(event){
        setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.reload(true);
    }, 5000); //5000 means 5 second After 5 second page is autmatically refresh
});
```

For More Description Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9xwkzg/)